# Error in python Voice recognition

Tags: python, python-3.4, voice-recognition

I have been trying to gain some knowledge of Python voice recognition, I have written a simple program that takes in what the user says and outputs what it 'thinks' the user has said.

My code is:

```
   import speech_recognition as sr
   r = sr.Recognizer()
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
   print("Say something!")
   audio = r.listen(source)

   try:
       print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
   except sr.UnknownValueError:
       print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
   except sr.RequestError as e:
       print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/speech.py", line 9, in <module>
with sr.Microphone() as source:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\speechrecognition-3.1.3-py3.4.egg\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 61, in __init__
self.format = pyaudio.paInt16 # 16-bit int sampling
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'paInt16'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks,
- space482

Answer (score 0):

pyAudio is a module that speech_recognition uses to connect to the users microphone.  An example of this is when you use:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
```

The .Microphone() class depends on an audio format aka pyaudio.paInt16 which is 16 bit.  Currently the APIs' used in this module can only use 1-channel(mono audio) so the bit size is set to a certain size with use install pyaudio.  However, this default size needs to be updated to use speech_recognition. To update this module use:

```
pip3 install PyAudio --upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

Google Speech Recognition uses PyAudio as a dependency. It is probably not installed correctly. Try installing from this unofficial repository:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Steps:

- Download your specific version
- Make sure the (32/64) bit matches your Python (32/64) bit
- Install the .whl file using pip